# why does `source` change the working directory?

Tags: r

Working with R 3.4.2. The problem is that using `source` with a relative path changes the working directory. Here's a minimal example:

The file tree: the `project` folder has two subfolders `src1` and `src2`. My working directory is `src1` but I'd like to use a function located in `src2`.

```
setwd("project/src1") #sets working directory where I want it
getwd() #prints "project"
source("../src2/myFunction.r") #loads the file with function I want
getwd() #prints "project" not "project/src1"
```

This only happens when navigating upwards. If I start with "project" as the working directory and do `source("src/src2/myFunction.r")` it doesn't change the working directory at all.

Is this a bug? If I specified a relative path it should be pretty clear that I do not want to change the working directory. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should check the file ../src2/myFunction.r.   Does it contain a `setwd` command?

Comment: I cannot replicate this in `3.4.1`. Are you sure there is nothing in that file you are sourcing that changes the working directory? Also in your question, shouldn't the first `getwd()` print `project/src1` not just `projects`?

Comment: Is the setwd() contained in another function? If so, and the function doesn't get called at the top level, I think that would be expected behavior

Comment: Ok yes I feel dumb now--there was code in the function I tried that called setwd